# Spring web application- java.lang.NullPointerException with jdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I am writing a simple spring 3.0 restful webservice with jdbcTemplate
but i get a java.lang.NullPointerException each time i try to access a resource.

I have created a DAO like this

```
public interface MisCodeDao {

    public void setDataSource(DataSource ds);
//the remaining method declarations
    }
}
```

And my DAOImpl like this

```
public class MisCodeDAOImp implements MisCodeDao {
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
public List<MisCode> findAll() throws MisCodeDAOException {
    if(this.jdbcTemplate==null)
    {
    System.out.print("JDBC TEMPLATE IS NULL");
    }
    return (List<MisCode>) this.jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT misCode, misClass, codeDesc, active from miscode", new RowMapper<MisCode>() {
    public MisCode mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int row) throws SQLException {
    MisCode miscode = new MisCode();
    miscode.setMisCode(resultSet.getString("misCode"));
    System.out.print(resultSet.getString("misCode"));
    miscode.setMisClass(resultSet.getString("misClass"));
    miscode.setCodeDesc(resultSet.getString("codeDesc"));
    String charValueStr=resultSet.getString("active"); 
    miscode.setActive(charValueStr.charAt(0));
    return miscode;
        }
    });


}
```

Here is what my application-context.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="misCodeDAO" class="com.tavia.bacponline.DaoImpl.MisCodeDAOImp">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

The full stack strace is here:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[bacponline]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet bacponline threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tavia.bacponline.DaoImpl.MisCodeDAOImp.findAll(MisCodeDAOImp.java:67)
    at com.tavia.bacponline.controller.MisCodeController.getMisCodes(MisCodeController.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class MisCodeController {
private Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Mashaller;
    public void setJaxb2Mashaller(Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Mashaller) {
    this.jaxb2Mashaller = jaxb2Mashaller;
}
private static final String XML_VIEW_NAME = "miscodes";
private MisCodeDAOImp miscodeImpl = new MisCodeDAOImp();

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/miscodes")
public ModelAndView getMisCodes() throws MisCodeDAOException {
List<MisCode> miscodes = miscodeImpl.findAll();
MisCodeList list = new MisCodeList(miscodes);
return new ModelAndView(XML_VIEW_NAME, "miscodes", list);
}
}
```

And my web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>com.tavia.bacponline</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/bacponline-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>bacponline</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>bacponline</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Thanks

Comment: So, which line is line 67 of MisCodeDAOImp.java? Because as the stack trace says, that's the line which causes the NPE. Also, you already asked 11 questions and accepted no answer. Why would we help you?

Comment: @JB Nizet, i am really sorry but really i don't see this accept link except Was this post useful to you? i click that. I'm really sorry. here is the line     return (List<MisCode>) this.jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT misCode, misClass, codeDesc, active from miscode", new RowMapper<MisCode>() {

Comment: Do you see the line JDBC TEMPLATE IS NULL in the output? Do you have any "caused by ... " after the stack trace?

Comment: @JB Nizet. yes i see JDBC TEMPLATE IS NULL

Comment: How do you get a reference to your DAO? What's the code you're using in MisCodeController to get your DAO?

Comment: How are you getting a handle to your `MisCodeDAOImp`?  Are you getting it from Spring's `ApplicationContext`, or are you instantiating it yourself using Java's `new` operator?

Comment: @JB NIzet. Thanks. Here is how i get my reference to the DAO private MisCodeDAOImp miscodeImpl = new MisCodeDAOImp();List<MisCode> miscodes = miscodeImpl.findAll();

Comment: @Nicholas. I am instantiating it myself like this

Comment: Spring does not inject into objects ***YOU*** create using `new`.  You would need to enable aspectj support for that to work.  You should be getting a handle to your `ApplicationContext` and asking for the bean you want.  Or else, if this is a web app, get the `DispatcherServlet` to do the work for you.

Comment: private MisCodeDAOImp miscodeImpl = new MisCodeDAOImp(); List<MisCode> miscodes = miscodeImpl.findAll();

Comment: @Nicholas, really, i don't know how to do that. is there any other way around?

Comment: Is this a web app or a standalone app?  It is going to be different depending on how it is used.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild, it's a web app

Comment: Edit your question to add some code for your controller and the `applicationContext.xml` that is used by your `DispatcherServlet` and also post your `web.xml`.  Do not post it in comments, as that will not be helpful at all.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild. i have edited as requested. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for you comments and suggestion. I have been able to get it to work by adding     <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean> to my app.xml

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something in your post... but here goes...

1. The Controller is an annotation based, please indicate the same to spring in the app context file.. also indicate the components to be scanned using
2. Rather than using

private MisCodeDAOImp miscodeImpl = new MisCodeDAOImp();

use the following for autowiring

```
@Autowire
private MisCodeDAOImp miscodeImpl;
```

Since you have already defined the bean in app context file, it should autowire.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i do not really understand what point 1 says. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Tom. I got it working by adding this line to my app-context.xml    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>. Thanks